# Show variation description on Shop page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm making a shop page that's showing every variation of the product as single products. Using [this](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wpc-show-single-variations/) plugin to achieve that. And I need the variation description to show up, too. However, I have no idea how to achieve this. I know there's a woocommerce_template_single_excerpt function, but that shows Attribute information, instead. So, this:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
```

Gives back Attributes titles (i.e. Size, Color). But is there any way I can pull out the description that's stored in every single variation inside the product?

Thanks a bunch in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I found a workaround, in a way, for anyone who runs into the same issue.

Because I had no idea how to access variation description, I created a new field called Shop Description:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_after_variable_attributes', 'variation_settings_fields', 10, 3 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_save_product_variation', 'save_variation_settings_fields', 10, 2 );
add_filter( 'woocommerce_available_variation', 'load_variation_settings_fields' );

function variation_settings_fields( $loop, $variation_data, $variation ) {
    woocommerce_wp_text_input(
        array(
            'id'            => "shop_description{$loop}",
            'name'          => "shop_description[{$loop}]",
            'value'         => get_post_meta( $variation->ID, 'shop_description', true ),
            'label'         => __( 'Shop Description', 'woocommerce' ),
            'desc_tip'      => true,
            'description'   => __( 'Shop description.', 'woocommerce' ),
            'wrapper_class' => 'form-row form-row-full',
        )
    );
}

function save_variation_settings_fields( $variation_id, $loop ) {
    $text_field = $_POST['shop_description'][ $loop ];

    if ( ! empty( $text_field ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $variation_id, 'shop_description', esc_attr( $text_field ));
    }
}

function load_variation_settings_fields( $variation ) {     
    $variation['shop_description'] = get_post_meta( $variation[ 'variation_id' ], 'shop_description', true );

    return $variation;
}
```

After that, I used a custom function and add_action to show it on the Shop/Archive page. You'll have to play around with the priority, as that's not sorted out here.

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item_title', 'show_woocommerce_product_excerpt', 35 );  
 
function show_woocommerce_product_excerpt() {
global $post;
if ( is_home() || is_shop() || is_product_category() || is_product_tag() ) {
   echo '<p class="excerpt">';
   echo get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'shop_description', true );
   echo '</p>';
}
}
```

And then, just add a description for each variation in your Products and it'll show up on Shop page without any issues.